# Ruby Date Calculation

Tags: ruby, date

This is not a problem so much as something I noticed and was wondering if someone could explain it to me.

If I use inline-type syntax I get two different, interchanging, answers:

```
irb(main):017:0> d = (Date.today >> 3) - (d.day + 1)
=> #<Date: 2013-06-01 ((2456445j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
irb(main):018:0> d = (Date.today >> 3) - (d.day + 1)
=> #<Date: 2013-06-03 ((2456447j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
irb(main):019:0> d = (Date.today >> 3) - (d.day + 1)
=> #<Date: 2013-06-01 ((2456445j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
irb(main):020:0> d = (Date.today >> 3) - (d.day + 1)
=> #<Date: 2013-06-03 ((2456447j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

If I do the same on multiple lines I get the same correct answer every time:

```
irb(main):025:0> d = Date.today
=> #<Date: 2013-03-05 ((2456357j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
irb(main):026:0> d = d >> 3
=> #<Date: 2013-06-05 ((2456449j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
irb(main):027:0> d = d - d.day + 1
=> #<Date: 2013-06-01 ((2456445j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
irb(main):028:0> d = Date.today
=> #<Date: 2013-03-05 ((2456357j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
irb(main):029:0> d = d >> 3
=> #<Date: 2013-06-05 ((2456449j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
irb(main):030:0> d = d - d.day + 1
=> #<Date: 2013-06-01 ((2456445j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Any ideas why this would happen? I am just interested to understand because, the way I see it, both ways should always return the same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Ruby's date format.

It is to do with when `d` is evaluated in each expression on the right hand side. Namely, at the start of the statement evaluation, and not again during it:

```
d = 1
d = 1 + d + d
=> 3

d = 1
d = 1 + d
d = d + d
=> 4
```

Answer (score 1):

`d.day` refers to the existing value of `d`, so when you change the value of `d`, the value of `d.day` changes and so to does the result.

If you want to achieve the result of your second example, replace `d.day` with `Date.today.day`.

Comment: Okay I see but why then does it return correctly every other time?

Comment: It returns correctly by chance because of the specific numbers you have fed in (1 and 3) to your formula. Other numbers and formulae treated like this might take longer to repeat, or even behave chaotically.

Comment: Assuming statement 16 was something like d = Date.today, in general your formula in the one-liner would alternate between the first day of the month+3 (i.e. June for March) and the (today-2)th day of that month. Change (d.day + 1) to (d.day + 11) to get more interesting chaotic behavour . . .

Comment: In fact I also noticed that "- (d.day + 1)" is not the same as "- d.day + 1", so even if you fix the use of d, the two approaches will give you a different answer (you'll get the last-but-one day of the month before the one you want, if you adapt the one-liners but leave the brackets in)

Comment: Thanks for the edification it just seemed strange to me but i understand now d has no value set originally so it uses 0 which also seems strange to me since I would have expected it to raise Nil error.